# Timezone aware datetime to string?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I am retrieving a timezone aware `DateTime` object from my postgres db.

Now I want to convert this datetime object into it's string representation.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
str(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 9, 59, 45, 165904))
'2016-01-15 09:59:45.165904'
```

But here I have:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 9, 59, 45, 165904, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I cannot find a way anywhere to find the `str` repesentation of the given object.

Comment: Does `var_with_timezone.strftime('%c')` help?

Comment: @AlexMorozov can you please post any example?

Comment: Please check out the lambo477's answer, he's talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of how to convert a `datetime` object to a `string`:

```
import datetime
import pytz

x = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 9, 59, 45, 165904, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(x, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

**Output**

```
15/01/2016
```

Options for the format string to pass into the `strftime()` function are in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).