# Return timezone aware postgres fields as a string

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'd like to use the `create_engine` parameters to get my timezone aware data out (in python), not as a `datetime.datetime`, but as a string representation of the UTC time it stores.

Specifically, I have:

```
engine = create_engine(DB_URI,
                       convert_unicode=True,
                       json_serializer=json.dumps)

conn = engine.connect()
res = find_all(conn, myquery)
```

But my dates come back like this:

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 14, 7, 30, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)
```

While I expect it to look more like:

```
2020-04-14 07:30Z
```

What can I change so that sqlalchemy will retrieve these values as text timestamps?

I expected the following to work as well:

```
PGTZ = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
    psycopg2.extensions.DATEARRAY.values,
    'PGTZ',
    lambda value, curs: value.isoformat() if value is not None else None)

psycopg2.extensions.register_type(PGTZ)
```

But this had no effect.

I've consulted other references:

- [Timezone aware datetime to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808721/timezone-aware-datetime-to-string) This doesn't help because it converts after query time, which is not what I'm looking for
- https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/psycopg2/2.7.5/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.register_tstz_w_secs This is promising
- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20130801121119.GA10036%40llserver.lakeliving.com This is about storage, not about retrieval
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43121970/1052117 This is close, but is about flask
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON this is close but serializes json in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`cast()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#coretutorial-casts) or [`type_coerce()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.type_coerce) functions?

The `cast()` function will use an explicit type conversion in the database, while the `type_coerce()` will only treat it as that type on retrieval into Python.

Comment: Can you help me understand how/where to use these?

Comment: In the select() part of the query? The manual has examples for both o them...